# Create sctp server and client using Asyncore module in python

Tags: python, sctp

How to create sctp server and client using Asyncore module in python.
It should work in both ubuntu and windows environment.

Comment: `import socket` and [read this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_Control_Transmission_Protocol)

Comment: My requirement is sctp server and client with Asyncore module.